# Howto redirect hardcoded URL to established SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, iptables

I have wireless USB modem, that has hardcoded URL for its GUI. The modem is usually accessible over 192.168.9.1 IP from LAN. This modem is connected to router behind NAT.

I need to access this GUI over internet (have public IP server available too) and trying to achieve that using both SSH tunnel and IPTABLES. I think I cannot use simple IP tunnelling as it is, because GET request from internet to GUI is immediately attempted to be redirected to hardcoded URL by that modem.

SSH tunnel is already up and running like this:

```
10888:localhost:80 publicIPserver.com
```

I attempted many IPTABLES rules both PREROUTING and OUTPUT but I cannot get connected. Either session is immediately dropped or there is endless timeout.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 10888 -j DNAT --to 192.168.9.1:80
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 10888 -j DNAT --to 192.168.9.1:80
```

Any direction to get this working would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic forwarding -D and putting a local host entry on the device you ssh to with the FQDN of the hard coded name?

Comment: As Aaron suggested, your problem can be easily solved using the dynamic port forward feature of ssh. After you established your ssh tunnel, you should be able to configure your web browser to use the newly created socks5 proxy, see http://sockslist.net/articles/socks-firefox-how-to

Comment: Thanks for hints. I was trying that, and  just realised that i have only dropbear ssh with no -D option. OpenSSH is an option to install but it will take time.

Answer (score 0):

On a computer behind the router:

```
ssh -R:9999:192.168.0.1:80 user@remote-public-accessible-server.com
```

On your local computer:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.1
ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:9999 user@remote-public-accessible-server.com
```

In this case, you will create a tunnel from the NAT environment to the remote server (a *rendezvouz* server). On your local computer, you create an alias for your home router, and use the public server to finish the connection.